# How to make chisquare goodness of fit not vulnerable to a single high values?

Tags: chi-squared-test, python, goodness-of-fit, scipy

There is an observation of a process, that I suppose to be a Poisson process.

[image]

And I'm trying to make a test, to check goodness of fit of my data with Poisson distribution.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats

# ... retreiving data and normalizing

x_by_one = np.linspace(0,50,51)
cnt = len(data)
ch2, pval = stats.chisquare(entries_normalized, cnt * poisson(x_by_one, *parameters))
print [ch2, pval]
# [815.78478004935334, 5.5111263499631125e-139]
```

The problem is that when **only one** measurement is great enough (has probability ~0.0001, but does happen), I got almost zero `p-value`. If I throw one data item off, `p-value` is almost 1. Can I somehow make a chisquare goodness fit test but without falling into `not significant` on a single jump? I assume there could be some math limitations which I'm not aware of.

Scipy version is `0.10.0`.

In addition: what does `chisquare` show when I pass not data but PDF (data normalized) to `chisquare()`? Looks like it makes small `p-value` equal to zero and almost 1 to 1.